# Any way to force laptop to re-check DIMM slot without removing RAM module?

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, asus, sodimm

Is there any way to get a laptop to re-check its DIMM slots without physically removing the RAM module(s)?

I have a laptop (Asus UX410UA) that has 4GB RAM soldered on board and an additional DDR4 SO-DIMM slot. It seems to have some kind of a motherboard fault: whenever the laptop gets disconnected from power (i.e. anything else than standby or soft reboots), it starts ignoring the RAM in the DIMM slot and reverts to the onboard 4GB only.

I have to physically open the machine and re-seat my RAM module in the slot, so it gets recognized again. I've tried swapping out the RAM module, to no avail.

Comment: The obvious first thing you need to try is (electrical) contact cleaning, both the memory module and the socket. I like to use *Super Contact Cleaner* from MG Chemicals. After cleaning, keep your fingerprints (i.e. skin oils) off the contacts!

Comment: Also look for bent contacts... though fixing them with a fine probe can be difficult, or impossible.

Comment: Thanks both! I didn't see any obvious dirt or damage, but I'll try cleaning it and having a closer look with a magnifying glass next time I need to open the laptop.